# Jquery drag-n-drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have this script, which to display window on screen:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "test.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
     $("#work-window").append(html);
  }
});
```

This window:

```
<div id="div-add" class="window">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="top-bar">
<td class="left"></td>
<td class="center">Add</td>
<td class="close"> <span id="develop-link-close">close</span></td>
<td class="right"></td>
</table>
Content
</div>
```

I need to do, that when click a center class, i can drag and drop this div (#div-add).

i tried make it with jquery Ul, but no result :(

```
$(function() {
    $( "#div-add" ).draggable();
});
```

How create this ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Where is `#work-window`? Doesn `#work-window` get populated with `#div-add` upon your AJAX call being completed? If so, you need to make the `.draggable()` call when your AJAX has completed and not at the top of the script

Comment: #div-add appears in #work-window. Ok, i try make the .draggable() when ajax completed

Answer (score 1):

Posting it as an answer here in case it helps anyone else

You're probably making the `.draggable()` call in your page before `#div-add` actually exists. Since `#div-add` exists only after the ajax call, you need to make the `$( "#div-add" ).draggable();` call once your AJAX call has completed.